# Change the color of outer dialog window

Tags: windows, nsis, nsdialogs

I want to change the color of the outer dialog window in NSIS. I have created pages using NSDialogs.

I recently change the size of this using 
System::Call 'user32::SetWindowPos(i$hwndparent,i,i,i,i 629,i 400,i 0x16)'

IS there similar way of changing the border/title bar color of this outer dialog windows?

Comment: I tried using SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_SETBKCOLOR} 0 0x000000 But this doesn't work!

Comment: I'm guessing the compiler gives you a warning that WM_SETBKCOLOR does not exist because..well, it does not exist...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the inner and outer dialogs with `SetCtlColors`:

```
Function myPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
SetCtlColors $hwndparent 000000 ccff00
SetCtlColors $0 000000 ff00cc
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

To change the non-client areas like titlebar and borders you need to use a [3rd-party plugin](http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/wiki/VCLStylesNSIS). I personally don't think this is a good idea but you can probably find several different NSIS skinning plugins if you want to force such things on your users...

Comment: Can we do this using System::Call 'user32::GetSysColor (10) System::Call 'user32::SetSysColor()